# How can I integrate djangocms-link in Ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I would like to use the functionality of the djangocms-link Plugin within the Ckeditor suche that I can add any and numerous links to my text.

So far I have only found this [feature](https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-text-ckeditor#default-content-in-placeholder). But this does not provide the flexibility I need (to add multiple links in various positions.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you seen the toolbar option in ckeditor that allows you to add plugins to your text content?